# jQuery trigger document event into a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, mousedown

I am totally new to jQuery.
What I wanted to do is filter certain events from going into a DIV.

I have following in my page

```
<div id="overlay"></div> 
<div id="GameDiv" style="width:1280px; height: 720px;"></div>
```

overlay has following style

```
  <style>
  #overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(1,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 200; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  pointer-events: auto
}
  </style>
```

I have following code

```
$(document).on(
{
    mousedown:mouseEvent,
    mouseup:mouseEvent,
}); 
$("GameDiv").on(
{
    mousedown:divEvent,
    mouseup:divEvent,
});
function divEvent(e)
{
    console.log("div event"+e);
}
function mouseEvent(e)
{ 
    console.log("doc event" + e);
    var evnt =  jQuery.Event(e.type,e);
    $("GameDiv").trigger(evnt)
}
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).on(
{
    mousedown:mouseEvent,
    mouseup:mouseEvent,
}); 
$("GameDiv").on(
{
    mousedown:divEvent,
    mouseup:divEvent,
});
function divEvent(e)
{
    console.log("div event"+e);
}
function mouseEvent(e)
{ 
    console.log("doc event" + e);
    var evnt =  jQuery.Event(e.type,e);
    $("GameDiv").trigger(evnt)
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(1,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 200; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  pointer-events: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div> 
<div id="GameDiv" style="width:1280px; height: 720px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting the document mouse event.
But I am not receiving 2nd div event.

What did I do wrong?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: because of position: fixed and z-index: 200 for overlay div, you never can receive the event of GameDiv

Comment: What I wanted to do is filter event using this overlay. And fire selected events into the div. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the both the events you can follow the below code snippet.

```js
$(document).on(
{
    mousedown: mouseEvent,
    mouseup: mouseEvent,
});
    $("#GameDiv").on("click", divEvent);
    
    function divEvent(e) {
        console.log("div event" + e);
    }
    function mouseEvent(e) {
        console.log("doc event" + e);
        var evnt = jQuery.Event(e.type, e);
        $("GameDiv").trigger(evnt)
    }
```

```css
#overlay {
  
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(1,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 200; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  pointer-events: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div> 
<div id="GameDiv" style="width:1280px; height: 720px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you really need to do it with `mousedown` and `mouseup` events u can follow the below snippet.

```css
 #overlay {
  
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(1,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 200; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  pointer-events: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div> 
<div id="GameDiv" style="width:1280px; height: 720px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on(
{
    mousedown: mouseEvent,
    mouseup: mouseEvent,
});
    $("#GameDiv").on("mousedown", divEvent);
    $("#GameDiv").on("mouseup", divEvent);
    function divEvent(e) {
        console.log("div event" + e);
    }
    function mouseEvent(e) {
        console.log("doc event" + e);
        var evnt = jQuery.Event(e.type, e);
        $("GameDiv").trigger(evnt)
    }
</script>
```

> Another solution

Refer the snippet below to call both the events at the same time

```css
 #overlay {
  
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(1,0,0,0.5); /* Black background with opacity */
  z-index: 200; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  pointer-events: auto
```

```html
 <div id="overlay"></div> 
<div id="GameDiv" style="width:1280px; height: 720px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on(
{
    mousedown: mouseEvent,
    mouseup: mouseEvent,
});
   
    $("#GameDiv").on({
        "mousedown": divEvent,
        "mouseup": divEvent
    });
    function divEvent(e) {
        console.log("div event" + e);
    }
    function mouseEvent(e) {
        console.log("doc event" + e);
        var evnt = jQuery.Event(e.type, e);
        $("GameDiv").trigger(evnt)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The 3rd method is working for me. Other 2 methods not working. Maybe the way I create the event is wrong?

Comment: I noticed you removed overlay position:fixed style. What I want to do is prevent certain events going into gamediv. So overlay act as a filter. I don’t want users to click gamediv directly. Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: @Janaka I removed it because your `overlay` Div was overlaying above your `GameDiv` Div. So it made `GameDiv` not to get triggered while making the call using the ID.

Comment: According to my knowledge what I would suggest is you can `hide` and `show` the two divs using an `if` condition

Comment: Is this the correct way of creating an event? var evnt = jQuery.Event(e.type, e);

Comment: You can refer this [link](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you have made 2 mistakes.

1. The overlay which is over the div you've applied the mouse events.
2. You should use the hashtag `#` in order to select by id attribute,
   also you have to use the dot `.` while selecting by class attribute.

```js
$(document).on({
  mousedown: mouseEvent,
  mouseup: mouseEvent,
});

$("#GameDiv").on({
  mousedown: divEvent,
  mouseup: divEvent,
});

function divEvent(e) {
  console.log("div event" + e);
}

function mouseEvent(e) {
  console.log("doc event" + e);
  //var evnt = jQuery.Event(e.type, e);
  //$("#GameDiv").trigger(evnt);
  
}
```

```css
#overlay {  position: fixed;  /* Sit on top of the page content */  display: block;  /* Hidden by default */  width: 100%;  /* Full width (cover the whole page) */  height: 100%;  /* Full height (cover the whole page) */  top: 0;  left: 0;  right: 0;  bottom: 0;  background-color: rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.5);  /* Black background with opacity */  z-index: 200;  /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */  pointer-events: auto}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- div class="overlay"></div comented just to illustrate-->
<div id="GameDiv" style="width:1280px; height: 720px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am getting the doc event, but I don't get the div event.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you should use correct selector: '#GameDiv' instead of just 'GameDiv' in your js.